# how to install cibersort in R, to do deconvolution using my RNA-seq Data with public single cell data

Tags: rna-seq, cibersort, deconvolution

I have RNA-seq Data from lung cancer immunotherapy patients but i don't have any single cell data from my sample, so i wanted to do a deconvolution with a public single cell data. I thought of doing the analysis with the cibersort website plataform but i wanted to obtain the results in R, to be easy to work with them.So i followed the steps in this article, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5895181/ :

```
library(e1071)
library(parallel)
library(preprocessCore)
source("CIBERSORT.R")
results <- CIBERSORT(‘sig_matrix_file.txt’, ‘mixture_file.txt’, perm=100, QN=TRUE)
```

But in when i did source("CIBERSORT.R"), i obtain this:

```
"Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'CIBERSORT.R': No such file or directory"
```

I don't understand i was supposed to have a file?

Comment: Is the R script available on the Cibersort website? I was looking for it some time ago but couldn't find. I don't have my credentials for the site on this computer so can't check now.